# php download script not working

Tags: php, download

The below .php script doesn't work for me - it just prints jibberish:

```
<?php
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/rapcDemo/documents/";
    $fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];

    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf":
                header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
                break;
            default;
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
                header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
        }
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
            echo $buffer;
        }
    }
    fclose ($fd);
?>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably not sending the right content type.

Comment: It's printing what ever is returned. When you say 'jibberish' what do you mean? For example if you try and echo an image you will get jibberish looking text

Comment: I am trying to download a .pdf document. It returns:

Comment: %PDF-1.4 %���� 22 0 obj <> endobj 44 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<39DB69944AE1588656E1D950E43C10AD><1F6A6DB51A7C3E4394EC3F068D20FA9B>]/Index[22 36]/Info 21 0 R/Length 101/Prev 69012/Root 23 0 R/Size 58/Type/XRef/W[1 2 1]>>stream h�bbd``b`�$�� ��{@bA� V!�u D<�A�ˀ�d �?�DH0n@BzL��HL�e`bdX �����?�ݯy�A endstream endobj startxref 0 %%EOF 57 0 obj <>stream h�b```g``2a`a`���π���@q��� �488@< �``�� �E�X,�����AwC�A�/��b,7|�o>�]��ߤ���W�����ȓ��H ���3 endstream endobj

Comment: I have noticed that when I type 'exit;' after the 'fclose($fd);' statement, the page wont show up at all.  Is the 'exit;' command really necessary (Im new to php)

Comment: Finally, I can remove the echo; however, shouldn't the downloaded file appear inside my downloads folder for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Well... This is the script I use. Maybe it will help.

Main donwload script:

```
<?php
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/rapcDemo/documents/";
  $fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];
  if(is_file($fullPath)) {
        # required for IE
        if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
        }
        # get the file mime type using custom function
        $mime = ($try = get_mime($fullPath)) ? $try : "application/octet-stream";
        # set headers for download
        header('Pragma: public');  // required
        header('Expires: 0');  // no cache
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($fullPath)) . ' GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: private', false);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_GET['download_file']. '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fullPath)); // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($fullPath);  // push it out
        exit();
  }
?>
```

And this is my get_mime() function:

```
   <?php
        function get_mime($url = "") {
            if (empty($url))
                return FALSE;
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $results = explode("\n", trim(curl_exec($ch)));
            foreach ($results as $line)
            if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type')
                return trim(explode(":", $line)[1]);
            return FALSE;
        }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I just found and modified a php script online that works like a charm:)

The link is below:

http://phpsnips.com/579/PHP-download-script-for-Large-File-Downloads

Comment: Feel kinda stupid too . . . all I really had to do was put the pointer to the document url in the loop that reads the file names in the <a href> tags and the browser downloads the file automatically! Dooh! Mideville school for the gifted:)